# Bootstrap Modal Issue URL variable

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, coldfusion-11

I am trying to display modal window when a users sessions times out. When the user times out they will get redirected back to the index.cfm?sessiontimeout page. I have the following code in the index.cfm page to fire IF the URL variable exists:

```
<cfif structkeyexists(URL,'sessiontimeout')>
   <script>
      //alert('Your session has timed out.');
      $('#appTimeOut').modal('show');
   </script>
</cfif>
```

All that happens is I see the modal background but not the modal window. However when I add it as a link in the nav (for testing), it works perfectly.

```
<a href="##" title="Feedback" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##appTimeOut">
```

Here is the modal window code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="appTimeOut" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">SESSION TIMOUT</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Your session has expired.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried moving the  and the modal window code between the two pages (index.cfm and header.cfm). Header.cfm is called within index.cfm. Either way, the javascript function doesn't display the modal window as expected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For data target you are used # 2 time can you use it once data-target="#appTimeOut"

Comment: You can set your script tag inner as   $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#appTimeOut').modal('show');
});